# Ubuntu Tablet Booting Trouble

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I bought aquaris M10 ubuntu tablet a week ago, opened and finished pre-installation (username, wi-fi etc) after that shut down the tablet. During shutting down process i saw an update in background but could not stop the closing so now i can not open my tablet and it stuck on splash screen.

I'm a experienced user on ubuntu but i don't know how to start to fix my tablet since it has no keyboard. Need your help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling may be an option, see https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/